# Create Column in Table after a Condition is Met

Tags: c#, mysql

I am just learning Databases and going with MySQL.  I am creating a C# form project to act a a rewards tracker.   The way this reqards system is used by the company I am building it for is that every $10 is a point. Like 19.99 is still just one point.  I got that logic down and know how to implement that.  What I want to do is create a table for transaction history. Where the table expands and starts with the Account# as the primary key and will also have transaction 1 as the start of the table.  After the first transaction I want to know how to Add a column for another transaction if transaction 1 is already filled.  How would I go about doing this in MySQL first and if anyone is feeling especially generous, how would I do this in C#?

I think this question is too specific, but my Google-Fu was not strong enough today.

Edit: I think I also want to make the transaction with as a string, with the total cost of the transaction and a timestamp.
Otherwise I think I would have to create a too many columns and overload the database

Comment: It sounds to me like you need to look into [Triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html).

Comment: I would absolutely avoid adding a new column for each additional transaction.  That's not good database design.  You should be adding records to your table for each new transaction, not columns.  What are all the fields you plan on including in the table?

Comment: @kelix I'm planning on having the account number as the primary key and transactions as the columns in one table. The other table will have account number, names, current transactions, points, points left to next reward, how many rewards collected, rewards used

Comment: Transaction records should absolutely be rows, not columns. You need to rethink your database design.

Comment: @ Andrew. Could you explain this. Or point me to a resource that explains this. I have most of my programming experience is formal education that never introduced data bases or expected you to know about it already

Comment: This is a very basic concept of relational databases. Get started here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database

Comment: @andrew. So would a primary key of time stamp with rows for the exact time of the transaction with columns for account number transaction number and transaction amount be a good idea?

Comment: Better, but don't use a timestamp for a primary key; transactions might occur at the same time. Use a unique transaction number instead.

Comment: @Andrew. I get it now. Thank you for all your help. I have up views your answers